# Best way to calculate 3D inverse Fourier transform of the inverse of a square

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-transform, 3d

I am facing the following integral:

$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int d\vec{q}e^{i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}}\frac{4\pi Q}{q^2+k^2} \tag{1}$$

so the 3D inverse Fourier transform of the function $\frac{4\pi Q}{q^2+k^2}$, where $Q$ and $k$ are simply constants. I wasn't able to solve it, and what is driving me crazy is that in my lecture notes (1) is referred to as a "trivial integral". What is trivial about it? What am I missing? The result of the integration should be:

$$\frac{Q}{r}e^{-kr}\tag{2}$$

How can we get to this result?

Comment: Haha don't panic, although I can understand why such a comment might get under your skin if you have been struggling with it for some time. Simply rotate to a coordinate system where $\vec{r}$ solely points in the $z$ direction, thus in spherical coordinates $\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r} = qr\cos\theta$, $\theta$ being the angular coordinate in spherical coordinates that measures angle from the $z$ axis. This is a standard trick that is easy to see once you have done it a few times.

Comment: @Gonçalo that answer does go about things in a harder way by integrating radially first and then being left with Bessel function identities. The trick I had in mind here which still makes the integral somewhat trivial (depending on your definition of trivial) is by doing the angular integral first, leaving the radial integral for last.